# Linux bash script doesn't run correctly, but when run at the command line everything is fine

Tags: linux, bash, rhel5, pg-dump

Originally I thought this was a db administration issue, but I think the lines have become a little blurred. I'm going to keep this strictly a scripting problem here. If you want more background info I posted this on ServerFault here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/511780/postgresql-pgdump-script-on-rhel5-failed-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplieddat

**My Script**

I distilled my original script down to this to keep things simple. This is what I have in a .sh named *pg_dump_script*:

```
/home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/postgresql/bin/pg_dump --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5433 --username=myusername mydbname
```

**When I run this I get the following error:**

```
$ bash pg_dump_script.sh
Password:
" does not exist  database "corenection to database "mydbname
```

I can copy and paste the line in the script file and run it from the command line and everything works fine.

**Here are the permission on the script file:**

```
-rwxr-xr-x

I used chmod 755
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here? I'm not an expert on scripting, but I thought if I could run it from the console it would of course run fine from a script. Let me know if any information is needed. I'm trying to keep this simple.

**Updates**

I removed all parameters. This is all the text in the .sh

```
/home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/postgresql/bin/pg_dump
```

I receive this error:

```
    $ ./pg_dump_script.sh
: No such file or directoryine 1: /home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/postgresql/bin/pg_dump
: command not foundst.sh: line 2:
```

Comment: Is that the actual error message? I'm not sure what a "corenection" is.

Comment: Yes, that's the actual error message copy and pasted. I know it seems weird. I really want to upload a print screen, because when I first saw it I thought my eyes were playing tricks on me.

Comment: It looks like one message overwritten upon another. Could you show perhaps the next line or two after the `pg_dump` call in your `.sh` script? Or better, remove everything in the `.sh` after that call and run the script again and see if you get a "clean" error message.

Comment: I use to have a lot more parameters, but this is the distilled version of the script. Added an update. I removed all parameters, and the only thing I'm doing is calling pg_dump.

Comment: And if you just enter `/home/myusername/lappstack-1.2-5/postgresql/bin/pg_dump` at a command prompt, what do you get?

Comment: It will prompt me for the password, and I then entered the password for the postgres user and it will perform a dump.

Comment: Your script contains DOS line endings; note how the carriage return is causing the error messages to seemingly overlap.

Comment: Ah good thought chepner, @enigmasck, try running `dos2unix` on your script file (make a backup copy of the script first).

Comment: I removed the newline. I'm still receiving the original error.

Comment: I'm using putty, but when writing this script I'm using vi. Would this be a problem?

Comment: holy crapppp.... dos2unix worked...Both of you deserve credit for this! Please provide an answer so I can upvote!

Comment: Great! @chepner gets credit for the "answer", but I'll take an upvote if you're given them away. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `dos2unix` on your `.sh` file to convert to proper UN*X line endings and it should work:

```
dos2unix pg_dump_script.sh
```

When editing with `vi` check to make sure it's not in `dos` edit mode. If you start with an original text file with CR/LF in it, `vi` will automatically go into `dos` mode unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: Another way is to use Notepad++.   From the menu select Edit →EOL Conversion → Unix